# How to implement an interface member with my own class in another class in c#?

Tags: c#, interface

I just wondering how to implement an interface member with my own class in another class. Here is an example to illustrate my question:

```
// --- Both files are in the same namespace --- //
// --- OwnClassA is in another namespace --- //

// --- First file --- //
// OwnClassA is importet
public interface ITest {
    OwnClassA varTest {get;}
}


// --- Second file --- //
// OwnClassA is importet
public class Test : ITest {
    public readonly OwnClassA varTest;
}
```

Visual Studio Code says: *'Test' does not implement interface member 'ITest.varTest' [Assembly-CSharp]*

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `varTest` is not a compliant name for a property. Consider renaming it to `VarTest` (note capitalization).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight That's just a convention. It can vary from place to place and has **nothing** to do with the correctness of a program.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That's why I posted this as a comment, not as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interface members must  be exposed as properties or methods, and the implementation has to match. The original interface member is a property. You have created a field. Make it an autoproperty instead and you should be good to go.

```
// --- Second file --- //
public class Test : ITest {
    public OwnClassA varTest { get; set; }
}
```

Or (if you want it to be 'read only' outside of the class)

```
// --- Second file --- //
public class Test : ITest {
    public OwnClassA varTest { get; private set; }
}
```

If you wish to use the `readonly` keyword (and thereby enforce that `varTest` can only be initialized in the constructor), you will have to use a fully-implemented property:

```
// --- Second file --- //
public class Test : ITest {
    private readonly OwnClassA _varTest;

    public Test()
    {
        _varTest = new OwnClassA();
    }

    public varTest
    {
        get
        {
            return _varTest;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The interface uses a property; the attempted implementation in `Test` uses a field. Those are treated very differently by the compiler and are not at all the same thing. Your `Test` class needs to define `varTest` as a *property*.

Answer (score 3):

The interface implementation needs to match the interface:

```
public class Test : ITest {
  public OwnClassA varTest { get; }
}
```

A field is not the same thing as a property; there is no way to say in an interface that an implementation must have a field.